# inserting javascript variable into php/mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have two file one is index.php another one is dbsubmit.php

In my index.php i got some javascript variable in between script tag..

var address = "Address of some places";
var latitude = 79.00256978;
var longitude = 125.89564725;

i want to pass these variables into my php script (dbsubmit.php) so that i can populate MySQL database. How can i solve this problem?? can anybody help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this and than in php using $_GET you can retrieve the values

```
<script>
function send(url){
var request;
try{
    request= new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    try{
        request= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            request= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4){
        //alert(request.responseText); this would be the value we get back, anything php would print would be alerted here
    }
}
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send(null);
}

send("dsubmit.php?address="+address+"&latitude="+latitude+"&longitude"+longitude);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to pass the variables to a PHP script, which in turn will be able to write them to a database.

Are you using some sort of javascript framework (jQuery, etc.) ? Because they make it really easy.
You just have to make another php script to get the variables from $_GET or $_POST and save them. AJAX effectively calls the php script passing it those vars.